# "Do ' shutil ' and ' listdir ' cause a conflict in python?"

Tags: python, shutil

The following is the error (in code format):

```
 File "/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc530/external/python/2.7.11-oenich2/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 119, in copy
copyfile(src, dst)
 File "/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc530/external/python/2.7.11-oenich2/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ' ./submit_z_/eraB'
```

Please note that the directory ' ./submit_z_/eraB ' is already there, i.e. it is apparently a problem with copying in it.

I have a different code that does almost the same job but with no ' listdir ' and it works fine.

Below is the code that produces the above error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import getpass
user = getpass.getuser()

prefix   = "data"
Appendix = "latest"
OutPath  = "/%s/" % (sys.argv[2])

import os
from os import listdir


jsons = {"All":"/afs/cern.ch/cms/CAF/CMSCOMM/COMM_DQM/certification/Collisions16/13TeV/ReReco/Final/Cert_271036-284044_13TeV_23Sep2016ReReco_Collisions16_JSON.txt"}
dir="/afs/cern.ch/cms/CAF/CMSCOMM/COMM_DQM/certification/Collisions16/13TeV/Era/ReReco/"
for f in listdir(dir):
    era = f.split("_")[-1].split(".")[0]
    jsons[era] = dir+f

workingdir = sys.argv[1]
while os.path.isdir( "./%s" % (workingdir) ):
workingdir += "_"
os.mkdir( workingdir )

from subprocess import call
call(["voms-proxy-init" , "--out" , "/tmp/.x509up_u%d" % (os.getuid()) , "--voms" , "cms" , "--valid" , "1000:0"])

file_sh = open ("%s/Submit.sh" % (workingdir), "w")
import shutil
from shutil import copyfile

for era in jsons:
    if not era.count("eraB"):
       continue

    print ("cp produceDataPU.sh" + " ./%s/%s" % (workingdir,era))
    shutil.copyfile( "produceDataPU.sh" , " ./%s/%s" % (workingdir,era) )

    file = open ("%s/%s/Submit.cmd" % (workingdir, era), "w")
    print >> file, "executable              = %s/%s/%s/ProduceDataPU.sh" % (os.getcwd() , workingdir , era)
    print >> file, "output                  = $(ClusterId)_$(ProcId).out"
    print >> file, "error                   = $(ClusterId)_$(ProcId).err"
    print >> file, "log                     = $(ClusterId)_$(ProcId).log"
    print >> file, '+JobFlavour             = "tomorrow"'
    print >> file, "environment             = CONDORJOBID=$(ProcId)"
    print >> file, "notification            = Error"
    print >> file, ""
    print >> file, "arguments               = %(JSON)s %(Appendix)s " % {
    "JSON":"%s/JSON.text" % (workingdir) ,
    "Appendix":Appendix
    print >> file, "queue %d" % (len(era))

    print >> file, ""

    file.close()

    print >> file_sh, "cd %s" % (era)
    print >> file_sh, "condor_submit -batch-name %s Submit.cmd" % (era)
    print >> file_sh, "cd .."


print "to submit the jobs, you have to run the following commands :"
print "cd %s" % (workingdir)
print "source Submit.sh"
file_sh.close()
```

Comment: What's your *cwd* (cause *"./submit\_z\_/eraB"* depends on it)? Also, what are the permissions on that file (and its parent dir)?

Comment: Substitute call  `copy( "produceDataPU.sh" , " ./%s/%s" % (workingdir,era) )` with `print(./%s/%s" % (workingdir,era))` and look what it returns. Maybe you missed a letter somewhere or wrote extra

Comment: @CristiFati My cwd is the dir from which I am executing the python file and to which the dir 'submit_z_' is created. 'eraB' is a directory. The python file is executable (chmod +x).

Comment: @AlexYu tried that, but it seems I get the path correct.

Comment: Try to create with `print`s a correct `sh`/`bash` script. E.g. `print("cp produceDataPU.sh " + " ./%s/%s" % (workingdir,era))`. And then try to execute by hand. Did you get a correct script?

Comment: @AlexYu works manually but not with the script.

Comment: I am glad for you! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take your to read articles in Help section. Especially recommended to use [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as guidance for future questions. In your case it would be better if you started your question with `tree ` or `ls ` of your dirs and paste json-content.

Comment: @AlexYu would it be helpful to list the full code?

Comment: Of cause. Ah! I misunderstood your previous comment as "I solved my problem". So: what was `print`ed ? Do you get  correct `cp` commands?

Comment: I got the correct `cp` comands yes but when implementing the `copy` in the script, it doesn't work.

Comment: @AlexYu please find the question edited to contain the full code.

Comment: And what the output of print `("cp produceDataPU.sh" + " ./%s/%s" % (workingdir,era))` was? Is it possible to execute lines from it in `sh`/`bash`? If `cp` commands are correct: what will became if you substitute `print` with `os.command`?

Comment: You must be in a centimeter of solution of your problem

Comment: Well, I took the output of `print ("cp produceDataPU.sh" + " ./%s/%s" % (workingdir,era))`  and executed it in the terminal. Result was that produceDataPU.sh was successfully copied in the subdir (era) of the dir (workingdir). I substituted the `print` command with `os.command` but then I get a different error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a leading space in the target filename you pass

```py
shutil.copyfile( "produceDataPU.sh" , " ./%s/%s" % (workingdir,era) )
```

that might confuse `shutil.copyfile` (in a quick local test that gives the error you are seeing).

Can you try with

```py
shutil.copyfile( "produceDataPU.sh" , "./%s/%s" % (workingdir,era) )
```

?

Comment: Worked! Thanks Pieter.